# Create two Ys in Chart

Tags: charts, data-visualization, mschart

I am using Microsoft Charting and trying to create a chart:
1 - X contains Dates
2 - Y contains Y1 and Y2 values
    Y1 can be a line chart and Y2 an area chart.

I tried the following:

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
Series series = new Series();

series.Points.DataBindXY(
  new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) }, // X
  new List<Int32> { 1, 2 }, // Y1
  new List<Int32> { 4, 8 } // Y2
);
chart.Series.Add(series);
```

But I always get an error:

Data points binding error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.

How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2):

Please add

```
series.YValuesPerPoint = 2;
```

before `series.Points.DataBindXY(`. This is the way to specifiy that each point have two Y values.